# Premature badge notification

Tags: support, badges, notifications

I just received a notification saying

> You've earned the "Enlightened" badge for [How to improve low quality answers consisting of only a code block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140040/how-to-improve-low-quality-answers-consisting-of-only-a-code-block/140065#140065). See your profile.

So I duly went to see my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235565/jirka-hanika?tab=badges&sort=recent) and this badge was not listed there.  Puzzling, isn't it?

Comment: See here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/182803/jirka-hanika?tab=activity , I can see your  badge'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are watching your Stack Overflow profile where you have not earned that badge yet. While you earned the badge on Meta Stack Overflow. See [your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/182803/jirka-hanika?tab=badges) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

I can see this badge on your profile, and you asked the question about 50 seconds ago.

My (somewhat educated) guess is that since you've visit your profile page before, you got either a cached version from your browser or from SO.

For stuff like this it is almost always caching.

Edit: It seems like you were visiting the main site profile, not the MSO one. hims056 seems to be spot on.

Comment: Actually I did the stupid mistake of not using the link to profile within the notification and landed at the SO profile.  However thank you for this idea as well.